# CAST date to number in order to do aggregate functions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

So I want to make my log_work_started column that currently is in Date format to a numeric value in order to perform calculations later on.

I am using the next query:

```
    SELECT
  Log_Work_started AS date
FROM
  `data_mkt.marketing_jira`,
  (
    SELECT
      Log_Work_started AS date,
      CAST(Log_Work_started AS FLOAT64) AS Log_Work_started_Float64
    FROM
      `data_mkt.marketing_jira`
    WHERE
      Log_Work_started BETWEEN "2023-04-01" AND "2023-04-30"
  ) AS test
```

But I got the next error within BigQuery: "Invalid cast from DATE to FLOAT64"

My expected output is to be able to perform a COUNT formula to count the number of days in the log_work_started column

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Lets assume we have a date 31 May 2023. To what number you want to cast it?

Comment: Why do you need to change a date to a number in order to perform calculations on it?

Comment: Basically to get the 2nd objective of my project. In essence is to get the AVG hours logged for each person. So what I want later on is to get for example Sergey had 22 days with logged time, what was his avg logged time in May? As this is going to live in an interactive dashboard I also need the data to filter itsef by different names and dates, so doing COUNT(log_work_started)/time_spent is going to give me that result. The problem is to convert the date to a numeric value in order to count how many days each person logged time

Comment: comvert it to seconds

Comment: Again, I’m not sure why you need to convert dates to numbers in order to count them. If you wanted to count the distinct days that someone logged time then, assuming log_work_started is a timestamp then you would do something like COUNT (DISTINCT TRUNC(log_work_started))

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. We don't know what data you've got, and what result you expect.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to simply cast a datetime to a number because what should said number represent? Rather, it appears that you're trying to retrieve the elapsed time between two datetime values, which itself could then be measured in seconds. Is that more aligned with what you're looking for?

Comment: Hello! I made another post being more clear with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517387/count-dates-in-sql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [COUNT DATES in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517387/count-dates-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax if you only want to count the number of DAYS.

```
DATE_DIFF(DATE '2023-04-01', DATE '2023-04-30', DAY) AS days_diff;
```

Comment: Hello! I made another post being more clear about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517387/count-dates-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SAFE_CAST instead of CAST. SAFE_CAST will help to handle any casting related errors. Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Unix Date will return a INT64

```
SELECT
  Log_Work_started AS date,
  UNIX_DATE(Log_Work_started) AS Unix_Date_Log_Work_started
FROM
  `data_mkt.marketing_jira`
WHERE
  Log_Work_started BETWEEN "2023-04-01" AND "2023-04-30"
```

Here is a page that shows valid data functions:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

Comment: Hello! I made another post being more clear with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517387/count-dates-in-sql