# COUNT DATES in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

So basically what I want is to count  how many hours each person logged by day, my dataset looks something like this:

| name | date | logged_time_(h) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ana | 05-01-2023 | 8 |
| Ana | 05-02-2023 | 6 |
| Ana | 05-03-2023 | 7 |
| Peter | 05-01-2023 | 7 |
| Peter | 05-02-2023 | 8 |
| Peter | 05-03-2023 | 5 |

My expected output is to count the number of days each person has data in order to perform a basic calculation later on, most precisely to get the avg logged time by day.

Currently I am using the next query:

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    subquery.dias_test
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Name, 
        date,
        DATE_DIFF(DATE("2023-04-01"), DATE("2023-04-30"), DAY) AS test_date,
        SUM(logged_time_(h)) AS total_time
    FROM 
        `data.table1`
    WHERE
        date BETWEEN "2023-04-01" AND "2023-04-30"
    GROUP BY 
        Name, test_date
    HAVING 
        total_timeo IS NOT NULL AND total_time <> 0
) AS subquery
WHERE 
    test_date BETWEEN "2023-04-01" AND "2023-04-30"
GROUP BY 
    Name, subquery.test_date
```

The issue with this first attempt in order to get the number of days for each person is that I get literally the difference between the monht, so in this case instead of getting 3 days for Ana and Pedro, I get 29 that is the difference between April 1st and April 30th.

Again, my expected output is to be able to say "Ok, Ana logged time in 3 days with an average time per day of 7 hours.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this? (:

Comment: Grouping by date is going to be a problem if you want an overall summary. Why are you filtering twice on the same date range?

Comment: Otherwise I get an error due the date_diff function

Comment: Well, I was mostly talking about the one in the outer query. But the sample data appears to be totaled at the date level already so I still don't understand what you're doing. In fact I don't know what you intention is with `date_diff()` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you try this query

```js
SELECT
  name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS num_days,
  SUM(logged_time_(h)) / COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS avg_logged_time_per_day
FROM
  logs
GROUP BY
  name;
```